# Removing column formatting in Excel worksheet using Python xlrd or xlutils

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlutils

What I am attempting to duplicate using Python 2 is the following MS Excel action -

1) Select All
2) Copy
3) Special Paste - without formatting

I have been pouring over xlrd and xlutils and although they have filtering capabilities
I do not see what I hope to accomplish. 
Or, to express it another way, I have a source worksheet that has been formatted
with merged columns, I wish to remove that formatting so I can extract the information using
some explicit reference to the cells or columns.

Any advice is appreciated,

Lou

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution - please see - [http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/10/pulling-data-from-excel-using-python-xlrd/#comment-379] [numbergrinder][1](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/10/pulling-data-from-excel-using-python-xlrd/#comment-379) on dumping spreadsheet data to a python datastore.